# How to execute a method on the window.Deactivate event unless the new foreground/active window is in a predefined list of windows?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, pinvoke

When the Deactivate event of window W1 is fired I want it to do it's go away & cleanup routine, unless the new foreground window is contained in a list of certain other windows. The other windows are all from the same process but run on different messagepump/GUI-threads. They are all winforms windows.
I created a Deactivate Routine that seems to be doing what I desire, but from the looks of it it feels like something to be ashamed of, so I wanted to ask you for a "cleaner" solution.
Explanation for the code sample posted below:
I lock because I believe I really don't want that monster to run twice at the same time under any circumstances.
I am doing the loop condition for the following reason:
foregroundWindowHandle is sometimes "0" instead of the handle of the window that is actually in foreground, unless I wait a few milliseconds (I tried 100) at the beginning of the Deactivate event. Since I am not sure those 100 ms guarantee me a not 0 foregroundWindowHandle I just wait until I can be sure it's not 0.
GetForegroundWindow() and GetWindowThreadProcessId() are the pInvoked methods of the same name.

Behold, my (working) attempt at solving this:

```
this.Deactivate += new EventHandler((a, b) =>
{
    if (!Monitor.TryEnter(deactivateLockObject))
        return;

    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            IntPtr foregroundWindowHandle = CSUTIL.GetForegroundWindow(); 

            if (foregroundWindowHandle.ToString() == "0")
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1);
                continue;
            }

            uint currentForegroundThreadId = CSUTIL.GetWindowThreadProcessId(foregroundWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero);
            if (new uint[] { threadidW1,threadidW2,threadidW3,etc. }.All((currentThreadId) => { return currentThreadId != currentForegroundThreadId; }))
                this.MakeInvisible(); // Executes the closing & cleanup routine

            break;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Monitor.Exit(deactivateLockObject);
    }
});
```

Comment: "Beauty is only skin deep, but ugly is to the bone."  Are you looking for style suggestions or algorithm suggestions.

Comment: I just don't feel comfortable with an infinite loop waiting for some pInvoke methods that don't behave as expected and I am open to any change that would replace my solution.

Comment: You'll get no argument from anybody that this is extremely ugly.  Getting to write code like this strongly hints at a rather severe design problem.  Clearly you are using threading when you should not.  A good example of the kind of debugging you'll have to do is available in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsui_team/archive/2012/10/31/debugging-windows-forms-application-hangs-during-systemevents.userpreferencechanged.aspx).  That was meant to scare you.  Don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring programming style, here are some suggestions.

1) Your event handler may run in the main gui thread or another thread.  If run on the gui thread, then "Sleep()" is inappropriate because it will prevent many other gui events from getting a turn.  You can force your handler onto the thread pool to avoid this.

2) In the old days, any delay less than 200 ms was likely to prevent other events from being handled.  Presumably, the scheduler decided that was not enough time to justify the overhead of saving state switching to a new event, and coming back.  It may not be the case now, but I still follow the habit of using 200 ms or more.  It may not add anything when the handler is not on the gui thread.

3) Your code as written is only an infinite loop if GetForegroundWindow() forever returns null.  In such a case, you have a system error or a corrupt program.  You should limit the time spent in the loop, and when exceeding that limit, treat it as a severe or non-recoverable error.

Here is a suggested modification that does these things.  Note that in your code, the Deactivate event handler did not return until done, while this example puts the work on a thread and returns right away.  The thread task will live at most 60 seconds before being returned to the thread pool.

```
        this.Deactivate += new EventHandler((a, b) => ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((obj) =>
        {
            if (!Monitor.TryEnter(deactivateLockObject))
                return;                
            try
            {
                int count = 0;
                int interval = 200;
                while (count < 60000)
                {
                    IntPtr foregroundWindowHandle = CSUTIL.GetForegroundWindow();
                    if (foregroundWindowHandle.ToString() != "0")
                    {
                        uint currentForegroundThreadId = CSUTIL.GetWindowThreadProcessId(foregroundWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero);
                        if (new uint[] { threadidW1,threadidW2,threadidW3,etc. }.All((currentThreadId) => { return currentThreadId != currentForegroundThreadId; }))
                        {
                            // do the work on the gui thread
                            this.Invoke(new Action(this.MakeInvisible)); // Executes the closing & cleanup routine
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                    count += interval;
                    Thread.Sleep(interval);
                }
                this.Invoke(new Action(this.HandleSevereError));
            }
            finally
            {
                Monitor.Exit(deactivateLockObject);
            }
        }));
```

Comment: Is there any advantage in using this threadpool instead of Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{}?)

Comment: The ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem() will wait for a thread to come available in the pool.  So if you want to limit the number of threads your application uses, the thread pool is good for that.  In your example, I don't think you don't need that feature.